# Is there a way to make naturally generated extra-large biomes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-data-packs

I'm trying to figure out a way for a 1.16 bukkit/spigot-enabled-server to generate biomes that are even larger than the classic "Large Biomes" settings (like WAY larger), but I'm struggling to find a way to get it to generate like that, even through datapacks etc? Does anyone have any ideas?